# how to display formula field in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, formula-field

I am using the following code to display formula field:-

```
<apex:outputField value="object__c.customFormulaField__c" />
```

Below is the controller code:-

```
   String queryString = 'Select Id,Customer_Status__c from Messages__c';
   List<Messages__c> listMessage =  new List<Messages__c>();  
   for(Messages__c msg : Database.query(queryString)){
        listMessage.add(msg);
   }
```

Below is the VF code:-

```
  <apex:repeat value="{!listMessage}" var="mod">
  <apex:outputField value="mod.Customer_Status__c" />
  </apex:repeat>
```

Below is the formula where Status__c is some other picklist field and Customer_Status__c is the formula field below which is to be displayed in visualforce.

```
   IF(AND(ISNULL(Opened__c),ISPICKVAL(Status__c,'Sent')) ,'New-Unread', 
   IF(AND(NOT(ISNULL(Opened__c)),ISPICKVAL(Status__c,'Sent'))        ,'Read',TEXT(Status__c)))
```

But it is not displaying . Can anybody tell me how to display the formula field in a visualforce page ? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: can you show the formula and the controller?

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are taking the value of outputfield incorrectly, It should have been value="{!mod.Customer_Status__c}" rather then value="mod.Customer_Status__c".

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to display it just like any other field, just make sure that the user viewing the page has access in their profile to that field.

Comment: No user has got all the permissions but still the field is not displaying.